# Converted MP3 format does not support for 11025 and 22050 Sample rate

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avaudiosession

I'm using LAME Encoder for converted Caf to Mp3 format. I give the sample rate 11025 . The LAME encoder converts caf to mp3. But converted mp3 file gives extra noise and duration. The problem same as 22050 sample rate.

But it works successfully for 44100 sample rate.Is there any way to change the mp3 buffer size for 11025 and 22050 sample rate.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in .caf. You should change the sample rate of .caf to 11025 or 22050 and then use LAME. But i dont recommend use both 11025 and 22050 for that, it will make the audio play bad.